# Truffle testcases with msg.value

Tags: solidity, truffle

How do we call contracts with `msg.value`? For example, below is my basic contract, but couldn't find anyway to write test cases in truffle.
So how do I write test cases for below methods?
`deposit()`, `deposit(unit amount)`, `deposit(address adr)` ??

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "./ConvertLib.sol";

contract MetaCoin {
    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value);

    function MetaCoin() public {
        balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }

    function getBalanceInEth(address addr) public view returns(uint) {
        return ConvertLib.convert(getBalance(addr), 2);
    }   

    function deposit() payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function deposit(uint amount) payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += amount;
    }

    function deposit(address addr) payable {
        balances[addr] += msg.value;
    }               
}
```

Truffle Test

```
var MetaCoin = artifacts.require("./MetaCoin.sol");

contract('MetaCoin', function(accounts) {
  it("should put 10000 MetaCoin in the first account", function() {
    return MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.getBalance.call(accounts[0]);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), 10000, "10000 wasn't in the first account");
    });
  });
  it("should return 20000 Eth in the first account", function() {
    return MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.getBalanceInEth.call(accounts[0]);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), 20000, "10000 wasn't in the first account");
    });
  });  
});
```

Comment: Where is your contract deployed on mainnet? I'm ready to exploit `deposit(uint amount)`!

Comment: :D Sorry, that was for an exploitable PoC!!!

Comment: You can get it from here.. https://github.com/aczire/smartcontract-exploit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
instance.deposit(accounts[0], {from: someAccount, value: someValueInWei});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported. In the near future it should be via the following syntax

[See pull request #94](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/pull/94)

You can use the `payable` and `value` options.

```
instance.methods['deposit()']
```

#### or

```
instance.methods['deposit(address)']
```

etc...

Comment: Ok, I have changed my method signatures. So no overloading for now.